# Martingale representation theorem and Markov property

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process, local-martingales

Martingale representation theorem says that every local martingale on $[0,T]$ adapted to a Brownian filtration is a Ito integral with respect the the Brownian motion generating the filtration.

The statement in itself is not surprising, since a martingale is determined by its terminal value. One can approximate the terminal value and then use Ito isometry.

But then, as a corollary, every local martingale on $[0,T]$ can be represented as a Markov process. This seems surprising---e.g. by induction, one can write down a discrete time non-Markov martingale . Anyone have a good explanation why this should be so? How does approximating the terminal value do away with path dependence?

Comment: Your "corollary" seems false to me. A stochastic process with an Itô representation may not be Markov (non-Markovianity may hide in the integrand). See for instance what happens for a process which is $0$ until time $1$, and then is a Brownian motion.

Comment: Right, good point. The space of Ito integrands need not give rise to SDE's where the diffusion coefficient only depends on the current state of the process.